# How can I provide continuous power to Nikon D5100?

Tags: nikon, battery, nikon-d5100, power-supply

I would like to shoot continuously with my Nikon D5100. I just got into the hobby and all I have are batteries. Does Nikon have a product where I can plug my camera into a wall socket, so I can practice shooting all day long without changing/charging batteries? I did some initial research, but could use clarifications.

Few questions:

- Is `EP-5 Power Supply Connector` the correct product for getting continuous power?
- If I need the EP-5, it looks like it's just the dummy battery with a plug. Is there an additional cable I need to get along with this dummy battery so that I can plug it into a wall socket for power? What product would that be if so?

Comment: Does this answer your question: [How can I run a DSLR from AC power?](//photo.stackexchange.com/q/76091)

Answer (score 1):

First, that's an interesting question.

IIRC, the EP-5 is an extension to the EH-5 AC power supply, so yes, you do need to plug that into the equation. See: https://www.nikonusa.com/en/nikon-products/product-archive/power-adapters/eh-5a-ac-adapter.html

There are also third party kits (like from polaroid) that also supply continuous power options. Try hitting Amazon for D5100 continuous power, there are a decent number.

However, keep in mind this is *your* camera. Nikon definitely knows your camera the best, and third parties should be considered riskier until proven otherwise. I'd feel okay with the Polaroid model, not so sure about some of those other "brands".

Comment: The Polaroid brand has little to do with the Polaroid company we all remember.

Answer (score 1):

Do you really need this? On a DSLR, one battery gives you an autonomy of several hundreds pictures.  I occasionally take several hundreds of pictures in a single day, when I go to an air show and use the burst mode. In that case I just put a fresh battery in the middle of the day (just to not try my luck, the battery could possibly last all day). And I take several hundred of pictures because the culling ratio is very high in that case.

Otherwise I wonder what kind of photography you could be doing where you take several hundred of pictures in a day, next to a wall socket. Taking 600 shots means taking a picture every minute for 10 hours in a row... Don't you check settings, lighting, etc? And this is a hobby?